TypeError: 'DataLoader' object is not subscriptable in SuperGradients Trainer
I've created DataLoader objects for my training and validation datasets, but when I try to pass them to the trainer.train() method, I get the following error:
Log summary:
TypeError: 'DataLoader' object is not subscriptable

Full log trace:
[2024-08-27 07:35:44] WARNING - sg_trainer.py - Train dataset size % batch_size != 0 and drop_last=False, this might result in smaller last batch.
The console stream is now moved to /content/drive/MyDrive/.../checkpoints/yolo_nas_version_m/console_Aug27_07_35_44.txt
An error occurred during training: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 309, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)  # type: ignore[possibly-undefined]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
TypeError: 'DataLoader' object is not subscriptable

Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-17-a2a5c064ba0b>", line 5, in <cell line: 4>
    trainer.train(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/super_gradients/training/sg_trainer/sg_trainer.py", line 1323, in train
    first_batch = next(iter(self.train_loader))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 630, in __next__
    data = self._next_data()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1344, in _next_data
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1370, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 706, in reraise
    raise exception
TypeError: Caught TypeError in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 309, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)  # type: ignore[possibly-undefined]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 52, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 52, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
TypeError: 'DataLoader' object is not subscriptable

My code to create dataloader:
from super_gradients.training.dataloaders.dataloaders import coco_detection_yolo_format_train, coco_detection_yolo_format_val
from torch.utils.data import ConcatDataset, DataLoader

# List of dataset folders containing COCO datasets
yolo_folders = [f'{LOCATION}/dataset1', f'{LOCATION}/dataset2', f'{LOCATION}/dataset3', f'{LOCATION}/dataset4']

# Load YOLO TRAIN datasets from each folder
train_datasets = []
for folder in yolo_folders:
    dataset = coco_detection_yolo_format_train(
      dataset_params={
        'data_dir': folder,
        'images_dir': f'{folder}/train/images',
        'labels_dir': f'{folder}/train/labels',
        'classes': dataset_params['classes'],
        'input_dim': (640, 640)
      },
      dataloader_params={
          'batch_size': BATCH_SIZE,
          'num_workers': 2
      }
    )
    train_datasets.append(dataset)

# Combine the training datasets
combined_train_dataset = ConcatDataset(train_datasets)

# Create a DataLoader for the combined training dataset
train_dataloader = DataLoader(combined_train_dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)

My code to create model and call Trainer.train()
import torch
from super_gradients.training import models
from super_gradients.training.losses import PPYoloELoss
from super_gradients.training.metrics import DetectionMetrics_050
from super_gradients.training.models.detection_models.pp_yolo_e import PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback
from super_gradients.training import Trainer

model = models.get(MODEL_ARCH, num_classes=len(dataset_params['classes']), pretrained_weights="coco").to(DEVICE)

train_params = {
    # ENABLING SILENT MODE
    'silent_mode': False,
    "average_best_models":True,
    "warmup_mode": "linear_epoch_step",
    "warmup_initial_lr": 1e-6,
    "lr_warmup_epochs": 3,
    "initial_lr": 5e-4,
    "lr_mode": "cosine",
    "cosine_final_lr_ratio": 0.1,
    "optimizer": "Adam",
    "optimizer_params": {"weight_decay": 0.0001},
    "zero_weight_decay_on_bias_and_bn": True,
    "ema": True,
    "ema_params": {"decay": 0.9, "decay_type": "threshold"},
    "max_epochs": 20,
    "mixed_precision": False, #Set to True if using GPU to speed up training
    "loss": PPYoloELoss(
        use_static_assigner=False,
        num_classes=len(dataset_params['classes']),
        reg_max=16
    ),
    "valid_metrics_list": [
        DetectionMetrics_050(
            score_thres=0.1,
            top_k_predictions=300,
            # NOTE: num_classes needs to be defined here
            num_cls=len(dataset_params['classes']),
            normalize_targets=True,
            post_prediction_callback=PPYoloEPostPredictionCallback(
                score_threshold=0.01,
                nms_top_k=1000,
                max_predictions=300,
                nms_threshold=0.7
            )
        )
    ],
    "metric_to_watch": 'mAP@0.50'
}

trainer = Trainer(experiment_name='yolo_nas_version_m', ckpt_root_dir=CHECKPOINT_DIR)

trainer.train(
    model=model,
    training_params=train_params,
    train_loader=train_dataloader,
    valid_loader=val_dataloader
)

If I do as below it works, but just using a single dataset directly:
trainer.train(
    model=model,
    training_params=train_params,
    train_loader=train_datasets[0],
    valid_loader=val_datasets[0]
)

Please give me some advice.
P.S: I know a easy fix would be instead of having multiple dataset folders I could merge it in 1 and use trainer.train() with a single dataset instead of a combined dataloader.
But the solution is growing and I need to split those datasets in case I want to test with few of them or additional datasets.

It looks like you are supposed to use a dataset rather than a dataloader. The code works when you pass a dataset, fails when you pass a dataloader. The object is not subscriptable comes from the code calling self.dataset[idx]. It is trying to call the __getitem__ method of the dataset. This won't work for a dataloader

Why don't ConcatDataset/trainer do what it is supposed to? I want to keep datasets in different folders.

The error here is because you are passing a dataloader instead of a dataset. The ConcatDataset has nothing to do with the issue. Read this to understand the difference between a dataset and a dataloader

The trainer expects a DataLoader wrapped around a Dataset.
If you only want to train a subset there are multiple possibly ways, from writing a custom Dataset class or using a custom Sampler that only returns indices within a selected dataset range.
The quickest method will be to just create a DataLoader of the dataset you want to use:
trainer.train(
    model=model,
    training_params=train_params,
    train_loader=DataLoader(train_datasets[0], batch_size=16, shuffle=True, num_workers=4)
    valid_loader=DataLoader(train_datasets[0], batch_size=16, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)
)


I really want to train multiple datasets from different folders because them I can test training with our without a specific folder(dataset). your solution works but don't resolve my problem. I could also merge all images and all labels in a single folder, but it wouldn't do what my project needs.

As said by Karl and Daraan, I was using ConcatDataset with an array of DataLoader instead of Dataset, I discovered it by printing the object type:
print(f"Type: {type(train_datasets[0])}")

Then I used the train_datasets[0].dataset of the dalaloader and it works.
